# KNEX: Como criar uma matriz a partir do resulta da consulta no SQLServer?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, knex.js

Eu estou usando o **Knex** para fazer uma consulta que uni várias tabelas vindas de um banco **SQLServer** (uso duas versão do SQLServer 9.0.3042 e 12.0.5000.0), exemplo:

```
knex('tabelaA')
    .join('tabelaB', 'tabelaB.idTabelaA', '=', 'tabelA.id')
    .select([
        'tabelaA.coluna1', 
        'tabelaA.coluna2',
        ['tabelaB.coluna1', 'tabelaB.coluna2']    
    ])
    .groupBy('tabelaA.coluna1', 'tabelaA.coluna2')
```

Preciso que o resultado de cada JOIN venha como um array no JSON, exemplo:

```
[{
    tabelaAColuna1: 'Texto',
    tabelaAcoluna2: 'Texto',
    tabelaB: [
        {
            tabelaBColua1: 'Texto',
            tabelaBColuna2: 'Texto'
        },
        {
            tabelaBColua1: 'Texto',
            tabelaBColuna2: 'Texto'
        }
    ]

}]
```

No Postgresql vi um exemplo usando ARRAY_AGG, porém esse função não existe no SQLServer.

```
knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(tabelaB.coluna1) as tabelaBColua1')
```

Como isso deve ser feito no **Knex** usando o **SQLServer**?

Answer (score 0):

Como solução para esse problema eu fiz assim:

1. Chamei uma consulta no banco com o primeiro atributo;
2. Fiz um MAP no objeto e para cada valor fui no banco e procurei o próximo atributo que queria e coloquei no objeto.

Para isso tive um problema com a Promises do Knex mas resolvi criando uma Promise no processo e usando ele para aguardar o resultado.

Fiz isso usando com ASYNC/AWAIT, :(

```
var atributo1, atributo2, resultado

atributo1 = await knex('tabela1')
  .distinct()

var resultado= atributo1

var resultsPromise = atributo1 .map(async (obj) => {
  atributo2 = await knex('tabela2')
    .whare('tabela2.atributo1', ojb.idAtributo1)
    .distinct()

  obj.atributo2 = atributo2

  return obj
}

resultado = await Promise.all(resultsPromise)
```

Isso ai, se alguém tiver alguma solução melhor estou ainda à procura.

Abraços!

[Antré Oliveira](https://github.com/anviol)